# asp.net - validating german date format is not working

Tags: asp.net, validation, view

**problem description:**

i am developing asp.net sites for a german company. in the view i have to validate a german date. i thougt, that would be easy but now i am desperated. in my views how can i turn on german validation. i searched stackoverflow, but i didn´t find a working solution for me.

e.g. entering german date in the format dd.mm.yyyy -> 13.04.2017 will always validate wrong date format.

**solution approaches:**
i have tried to set the cultureinfo, but my problem is the frontend validation.

thx for your help

Comment: What has date got to do with german/french? Date only changes format depending upon user's preference.

Comment: In the validator there must be an option of setting what format of date you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code for front end validation.
Basically validate using this regex `/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\- \/.](?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\- \/.](201)[2-9]{1})$/`.
It will work for **13.04.2017, 13/04/2017 and 13-04-2017** formats.

```js
if("13.04.2017".match(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\- \/.](?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\- \/.](201)[2-9]{1})$/) != null){
  $("#result1").html("TRUE");
}else{
  $("#result1").html("FALSE");
}

if("77.04.2017".match(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\- \/.](?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\- \/.](201)[2-9]{1})$/) != null){
  $("#result2").html("TRUE");
}else{
  $("#result2").html("FALSE");
}

if("13.66.2017".match(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\- \/.](?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\- \/.](201)[2-9]{1})$/) != null){
  $("#result3").html("TRUE");
}else{
  $("#result3").html("FALSE");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>is "13.04.2017" valid date: </span><b><span id="result1"></span></b><br>
<span>is "77.04.2017" valid date: </span><b><span id="result2"></span></b><br>
<span>is "13.66.2017" valid date: </span><b><span id="result3"></span></b><br>
```